# Creating a new JSON import instance

Tags: javascript, json, express

so I have an object in JSON format: object.json.

And on every http call it's used in the method `getAlbum()`, but if I make multiple requests, the JSON gets cached, because it imports at the upper of the page.

How can I create a new instance to clear the JSON every time?

It has a lot of fields and depth, so I just can't create a `new Object()`;

```
const albumReportJSON = require('./album.report.json');

const getAlbum = async(ctx) => {
  const value = albumReportJSON;
  /.. processing
}
```

Comment: Also, maybe there is a better solution than just looping through all keys and setting to 0

Answer (score 0):

Require the json inside your function

```
const getAlbum = async(ctx) => {
  const albumReportJSON = require('./album.report.json');
  // Or just do const value = require('./album.report.json');
  const value = albumReportJSON;
  /.. processing
}
```